# Using pee command with quotes in command

Tags: shell, pee

I have the following shell command which I need to use for sending output of code to two parallel commands.

```
cat /data/market_voices_spam_classifier/v5/logs/server.log | sh mapper.sh | python2.7 reducer.py | pee 'tee spammers-`date -d "-1 days" +%Y-%m-%d`' 'EMAIL=noreply mutt -s Test_Mail mail_id@gmail.com'
```

While it works perfect just a small problem is that I wish to change the mail subject here from `Test_Mail` to `'Test Mail'` for which I need to use quotes in the pee command and then it doesn't work as it should not.

Comment: haha pee tats so funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with quotes, needed to just use double quotes, in the pee command

```
cat /data/market_voices_spam_classifier/v5/logs/server.log | sh mapper.sh | python2.7 reducer.py | pee 'tee spammers-`date -d "-1 days" +%Y-%m-%d`' "EMAIL=noreply mutt -s 'Test Mail' mail_id@gmail.com"
```